# Can I develop and test IBM Bluemix application in local environment?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I am trying to understand the application development life cycle for IBM bluemix application development. The bluemix document mentions about using Git, Eclipse or CF to push the application to bluemix cloud. I would like to know if I can develop the full application in the local environment, with connectivity to bluemix cloud?. I want to develop it locally and test it, before I can deploy/push into the cloud.

Comment: If you are using git for development, you will create a local copy of the repository, so in fact you are developing on your local machine.

Comment: Okay. So the application will also run locally and connect to bluemix services?

Comment: You can run the application locally and after testing it, you can deploy it to Bluemix (see for an example here: [Bluemix first time experience](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/12/15/create-deploy-modify-redeploy-first-bluemix-app/))

Comment: There is a DW001 course that is hands-on in developing a small app locally with testing and deployment to Bluemix.  I found it good.  https://developer.ibm.com/dwcourses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a Git repository for your application. You can do it clicking on the "Add git" button within your application dashboard (it will create your repo in [IBM Bluemix DevOps Services](https://hub.jazz.net/)) or you can just create manually your own repo (e.g. on [GitHub](https://github.com/)) with the starter code of the runtime you chose.
Once you have created your repository, you can clone it on your local machine using the [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) command. This allows you to work on your local copy, testing it on your machine.

Your application will have probably some services bound to it, so you should decide which services you want to replicate in your local environment and which services you want to use remotely (e.g: you might want to connect directly to your SQL DB service instance on Bluemix or you might want to create a local version of the DB on your machine). Please note that some services could not allow remote connection from your local environment: refer to the docs of each specific service you need.

Whatever you decide you can develop and test the full application on the local environment. Once you have finished you can use the [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) command to deliver your changes to the repository and then use the [cf push](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#push) command to deploy your application to Bluemix.

Consider that if you need to automate your builds and deployments you can take a look at [IBM Continuous Delivery Pipeline for Bluemix](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/DeliveryPipeline/index.html#getstartwithCD). You can also use it in [DevOps Services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-intro4-app/index.html).

Comment: Ok. I understand this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding info about Eclipse and cf, you can use:

1. Eclipse on local to develop/test your application and push it to Bluemix
   trough the Eclipse Bluemix plugin. Please find some info at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/deploy_eclipsetools.html
2. "cf push" command can be used in the CLI after having developed/tested your
   code on local. Please find some info at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/upload_app.html